# Facebook SDK for Android throwing an error - "user logged in as a different Facebook user"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-permissions

Facebook Android SDK 4.0 throws an error stating that the user is already logged in with a different account when additional permissions are requested. This only happens when  user is logged in as a different user on the Facebook app

Flow:
-User is logged in as "xyz" on the Facebook App.
- User opens myapp and logs in as "abc" on facebook . 
- User declines "user-friends" permission. 
- When the app is closed and run again , I am again requesting "user_friends" permission if it has not been provided.
- Facebook returns an error stating that the user is logged in as a different user .

When user is logged in as a different user on Fackbook app, the request for additional permissions returns the error

Comment: When you reopen the app, does it logs in with "abc" or with "XYZ". If it uses "XYZ" to login than you will get that error.

Comment: It uses the same account which was used to login into myapp i.e "abc"